# How to get input custom values and pass it to variables from multi selection criteria with Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this form with a multi-selection blocks, I am trying to get the values of each block criteria on click so I can send it a database, but every time I click a block my script is getting the value of all, any ideas?

I created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/Hqbmk/4/

```
<form action="" method="post" id="postingFeedback">

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                <li class="vote" name="vote1" value="A-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote1" value="A-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote1" value="A-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote1" value="A-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->

<div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                <li class="vote" name="vote2" value="B-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote2" value="B-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote2" value="B-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote2" value="B-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="C-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="C-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="C-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="C-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="D-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="D-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="D-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote3" value="D-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                <li class="vote" name="vote4" value="D-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote4" value="D-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote4" value="D-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote4" value="D-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- .votes-list -->
            <ul class="vote-list">
                   <li class="vote" name="vote5" value="E-value1">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote5" value="E-value2">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote5" value="E-value3">
                </li>
                <li class="vote" name="vote5" value="E-value4">
                </li>
                <input name="smileVote" class="is-hidden" data-role="none" value="" />
            </ul><!-- / .votes-list -->
            <div class="clear"></div>

</form>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function getValues(){    
    $('#postingFeedback li').on('click', function(event){        
           var $clickedValue = $(this).val($(this).attr("value")); // Retreive "value"
           $(this).siblings('input[name="smileVote"]').val($clickedValue); // Plug smile value into input for database POSTS
    });
}



getValues();
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a reserved attribute, it's not intended to be used on an `li` like you're trying to do. Rename that to something else, like `vote`:

```
<li class="vote" name="vote1" vote="A-value1">
```

Then get the value by accessing the attribute directly:

```
$('#postingFeedback li').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).siblings('input[name="smileVote"]').val($(this).attr('vote'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give different name to each input. form send data in key value pair where it take name as key. since all input box has same name it will only one key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.serializeArray()`

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click' , function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var  a = $(':input').serializeArray().get();
    console.log(a);
});
```

You can use the **var a** to send it to your Database

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Hqbmk/5/)**